# Setting QML button background by QtQuick Styles

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

I encounter many difficulties while I try to set my Button background following the [documention](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-buttonstyle.html).

For some reason Qt doesn't find the import `QtQuick.Controls.Styles`. I've tried to import it in many ways but without success. My last try:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Button {
    id: btn
    property int row
    property int col
    property Item buttonPreview
    property bool hasPreview: true
    GridLayout.row: row
    GridLayout.col: col
    GridLayout.colSpan: 2
    GridLayout.rowSpan: 2
    width: 50
    height: 50

    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
                 color:"white"
                }
    }

...

}
```

I encounter the following errors:

1. `import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2` code is underlined saying that `QML module not found`
2. `Btn.qml:21:5: Cannot assign to non-existent property "style"` appears when I am using the application.

Strange thing that if I remove the `import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2`, the `style: ButtonStyle {`  becomes underlined.

I use `Qt 5.3.2`.

Part of my .pro configuration file:

```
QT       += core gui svg xml network quick gui-private qml quickwidgets widgets concurrent
TARGET = ProjectName 
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++12 plugin
```

Any idea is appreciated, really thanks for the time for helping solving my problem.

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? What's in `<qtdir>/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles`?

Comment: I have 2 directory and a file under `qml\QtQuick\Controls\Styles`: Base, Desktop directories and qmldir file.

Comment: Btw, I think `CONFIG += c++12` must be `CONFIG += c++11`.

Comment: Good point the should be c++11. My version of Qt creator is 3.1.

Comment: did u solve the problem. i also has the same issue i cant set the  background

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem with the module not found, I think, is with the previous version of Qt. You should remove Qt5.2, using the maintenance tool.
   After that, I tried your QML code in a `Window` and it worked (of course after removing the `GridLayout`s).
2. `GridLayout` requires the module `import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1` and is applied to a `Grid`, but you have no `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

`import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2`

to

`import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0`